# Create Sheets from column values, and insert values in column in specific cells on each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro that reads values in Column A on "Sheets Insert", creates individual worksheets based on those values, and then copies "Template" to each new page.

```
Sub NewSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("Sheets Insert")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=sh
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

It works great.

So the next step for me is to take the value the worksheet was created from in Column A of "Sheets Insert", and insert that value at G3 of the created worksheet.

Then I need it to take the value in the same row in column B of "Sheets Insert" and copy it into C3 on that page.

So for example:

"Sheets insert"

```
Column A   |   Column B

Motor A         12345
Motor B         23456
```

Code creates sheet Motor A and pastes Motor A to [g3] and pastes 12345 to [c3] on Motor A sheet.

Code creates sheet Motor B and pastes Motor B to [g3] and pastes 23456 to [c3] on Motor B sheet.

And so on down the list. I searched for a couple of hours and had no luck. Hoping someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Start with recording a macro and see how you can alter the output so it is reusable. 
That you ctrl+C-V'd some code doesn't mean you're stuck now - from what I see no attempt has been made yet, and SO is not a free coding service. Not trying to be negative and I won't downvote this, but tell us why you're not managing to have the "copy paste through code" work. 
How does your current attempt behave and what is the desired behavior?
In other words - where are you stuck? And "I haven't found somebody who did my exact job before me" is not a place to be stuck at.

Comment: Mate, I'm just a guy trying to put together a spreadsheet. This isn't my job or anything. I'm way out of my depth. I tried recording the macro but I'm not even at the point where I'd know how to add it. I can spend the next year of my life figuring out what i'm doing, just so I can slap together a spreadsheet, or I can ask for help. So like I said, the code creates the pages from the column, but i wouldn't have the first clue how to copy from two columns into specific cells.

Comment: I've learned a few things from tutorials that have helped me with some other fixes, so even if someone wanted to point me to a tutorial that is going to make it so I can fix it myself, that would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question you have to add two rows of the code:

```
Sub NewSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("Sheets Insert")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

For i = 2 To Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=sh
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value

        'add code
        Range("G3") = sh.Range("A" & i) 'copy name into cell G3
        Range("C3") = sh.Range("B" & i) ' copy data into cell C3
Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You're a legend man. Thanks heaps for taking the time Ferdinando. That works perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome @lenovomonitor...if you think the answer is useful, you can vote it ... thanks